# BlackBerry Error

Tags: android, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-qnx, blackberry-android

I am trying to developing an android app for blackberry Playbook. For this i have installed all the necessary tools for blackberry development in android.For month ago i run some android apps on BB playbook. for this a debug token is needed which expired in a month. then today i develop a new debug token and run my new android app on BB Playbook but its not running and gives lots of errors and a red cross on the project folder i don't know why its happening.

[image]

Comment: Screenshots are not nice as you can not extract and search for the content later. It would be better to edit your question and copy and paster the error messages into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the timing of this issue coincides with the r21 release of the Android SDK which is not currently supported by the 1.3 beta release of the BlackBerry plug-in for ADT. For the time being, you can downgrade to r20 or wait for the next beta update of the plug-in (v1.4) at the end of the month.

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade the tools to r20 by following the instructions here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/Google-ADT-21-Not-Currently-Supported/td-p/1988013